# Is there no correct answer on this question?

Tags: physics, graphing-functions

Again, this is the link to the Imgur post I made to get the photo online: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq8qH.jpg
This was a question on an exam I recently conducted, and the results said that option "A" was the correct answer, however it doesn't look like "A" has any curve, whereas when I graphed it after the test there seemed to be a graph. My teacher said that the first few dots may not be used due to inaccuracy, but the graph should still be different. What is the answer to this question (if there is one),  because I'm trying to see if I would be able to gain extra marks?
Thank you so much, this means a lot to me.

Comment: Should we look at those dots from left to right, or the other way round? How to tell which dot represents the first/second/etc time?

Comment: Assuming the object moves from left to right, and that the displacement is measured at regular intervals (say every second), then the answer is surely D.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I think since the dots are unlabeled in time, any reasoning that says A is correct can equally be applied to say that B is correct. Similarly for C/D.

Comment: Dots from left to right. Also, it said that the time intervals are the same, and by looking it’s constantly moving forwards. Again, is a displacement time graph, not velocity time. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: If left to right, I think the dots being bunched in the center means the displacement / position should spend more time in the middle of the graph, so I'd expect a shape similar to that of the $\arcsin$ curve: steep slope at the beginning and end, but a more flat slope (not moving very fast) in the middle.

Comment: My assumtion at the moment is that those graphs represent the "velocity vs. time graph" of the motion, and somebody made a mistake saying it was "displacement vs. time graph". Then D) would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers are right. Let's take the right direction to be the direction of positive displacement (which is a reasonable assumption, because that's usually the assumption for such multiple choice questions).

Based on the very limited information given, I'll assume the simplest possible setup; namely that the object keeps moving to the right. As a result, the displacement $s$ needs to be an increasing function of $t$. This immediately eliminates $B,C,D$. Finally, $A$ is wrong because it depicts a constant slope, which means the velocity is constant; this is incorrect, because if the velocity really was constant, then the dots would be evenly spaced apart (because the dots are taken equal time intervals apart).

The correct graph (under the assumptions stated above) should look something like an $\arcsin(x)$ graph or a $\sinh(x)$ graph. The slope should initially be positive and high in magnitude (i.e it is moving a large distance in a given time interval), then somewhere in the middle, it should still be positive, but slightly lower in magnitude (it travels smaller distance in same time interval), then at the end the slope should be positive and high in magnitude again (it moves a large distance in the same time interval).

---

Also, the reason given by your teacher that "first few dots may not be used due to inaccuracy" makes no sense. First of all, there is no such information given in the question to suggest that this is an experiment performed by a student or any other contextual clues to suggest that the first few data points should be ignored. So, the most reasonable assumption (in the given situation of a multiple choice question on what looks to be a high-school level exam) one can make for the question is to assume that the given information is perfect, without any sort of experimental error.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer helps a lot, especially with the final paragraph about how the data should be taken as perfect, which just further clarifies how wrong the question is.

Comment: @MooseLovell Another reason why the proposed suggestion of ignoring first few is wrong is because what is the meaning of "first few dots"? There is no quantitative information given in the question to decide which dots are the "bad ones" to be ignored and which are the "good ones" to be taken into account. The only way I can try to make sense of the graphs is to think of $D$ as the velocity-time graph... but even that is kind of reaching for straws.

Comment: Nice answer: Note that "Because the object keeps moving to the right..." is not in any way given. It could be a motion where the first point  (time-wise) point is the middle one, then next (time-wise) is the rightmost, etc. Of course, none of proposed pictures show that behaviour, so still none are right.

Comment: @Ingix yup, absolutely; I'll clarify my post to show that it is an additional assumption made by me. Based on the very limited information given I've had to make a bunch of additional assumptions. But again, given the context of the question (exam setting in what looks to be middle/high-school level), I think the best (and really the only reasonable) thing to do is assume the simplest possible setup. Because if the question intended anything but the simplest/most naive interpretation, then it should have been stated so very clearly, otherwise that's just misleading and unfair to any student.